# What is the difference between npm 3 vs Bower?

Tags: node.js, bower

With npm 3 coming with a flat(-ish) dependency structure, do we use Bower in future or just npm 3 when its released ?

> npm is most commonly used for managing Node.js modules, but it works for the front-end too when combined with Browserify and/or $ npm dedupe.
>
> Bower is created solely for the front-end and is optimized with that
> in mind. The biggest difference is that npm does nested dependency
> tree (size heavy) while Bower requires a flat dependency tree (puts
> the burden of dependency resolution on the user)

[merge bower into npm](https://github.com/bower/bower/issues/1520)

[npm3](http://blog.npmjs.org/post/122450408965/npm-weekly-20-npm-3-is-here-ish)

[npm-and-front-end-packaging](http://blog.npmjs.org/post/101775448305/npm-and-front-end-packaging)

Answer (score 6):

npm 3 coupled with [browserify](http://browserify.org/) or [webpack](https://webpack.github.io/) is the way to go now. Multiplying package manager in your project make your workflow harder.

Install npm 3 today with:

```
npm install -g npm@latest
```

Comment: and how do you couple it with one of those? can you provide some links/demos or something?

Comment: Links are provided to both projects. Read their documentation to have an idea of what each of them are capable of, and on how to achieve what you need.

Comment: I agree with you on not to use multiple package manager. Should we use npm 3 along with browserify rather than using Bower?

Answer (score 1):

- Bower is mainly for frontend libraries, which do not have
  dependencies of their own, thus in bower, flat structure is a
  limitation, rather than a feature.
- npm-3 is a smart dependency manager where dependencies can have their
  own secondary dependencies (sub-dependencies).
- It tries to create flattened structure wherever possible, but that is
  not a limitation. In certain cases, it will not adhere it (for   example : when you need multiple version of a dependency)